# SQL inner join multi part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure with a bunch of joins I can not figure out why this is not working - I get an error:

> The multi-part identifier "[table.column]" could not be bound.

This is an altered bit of SQL the original is -

```
    dbo.Release 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Cartridge 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.PriceClass AS PriceClass ON dbo.Cartridge.PriceClassId = PriceClass.Id 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.CartridgeType ON dbo.Cartridge.CartridgeTypeId = dbo.CartridgeType.Id 
    ON dbo.Release.Id = dbo.Cartridge.ReleaseId 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.OemSegmentation 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.OemProduct ON dbo.OemSegmentation.OemProductId = dbo.OemProduct.Id 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.OemPlatform ON dbo.OemSegmentation.OemPlatformId = dbo.OemPlatform.Id 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.OemMediaType ON dbo.OemSegmentation.OemMediaTypeId = dbo.OemMediaType.Id 
    ON dbo.CartridgeType.Id = dbo.OemSegmentation.SupplCartTypeId  
       OR dbo.CartridgeType.Id = dbo.OemSegmentation.CartridgeTypeId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.CartridgeCoverage ON dbo.Cartridge.Id = dbo.CartridgeCoverage.CartridgeId
```

What I am trying to change it to -

```
    dbo.Release 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Cartridge 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.PriceClass AS PriceClass ON dbo.Cartridge.PriceClassId = PriceClass.Id 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.CartridgeType ON dbo.Cartridge.CartridgeTypeId = dbo.CartridgeType.Id 
    ON dbo.Release.Id = dbo.Cartridge.ReleaseId             
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.OemProduct ON OemSegmentation.OemProductId = dbo.OemProduct.Id 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.OemPlatform ON dbo.OemSegmentation.OemPlatformId = dbo.OemPlatform.Id 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.OemMediaType ON dbo.OemSegmentation.OemMediaTypeId = dbo.OemMediaType.Id        
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.CartridgeCoverage ON dbo.Cartridge.Id = dbo.CartridgeCoverage.CartridgeId
```

The error happens on these lines

```
INNER JOIN 
     dbo.OemProduct ON OemSegmentation.OemProductId = dbo.OemProduct.Id 
INNER JOIN 
     dbo.OemPlatform ON dbo.OemSegmentation.OemPlatformId = dbo.OemPlatform.Id 
INNER JOIN 
     dbo.OemMediaType ON dbo.OemSegmentation.OemMediaTypeId = dbo.OemMediaType.Id
```

Comment: Can you post the real error message? The `"[table.column]"` part should say exactly where the problem is. I can suggest using simple letter aliases like `C` or `P` instead of repeating the same table name

Comment: in statement `INNER JOIN dbo.OemProduct ON OemSegmentation.OemProductId = dbo.OemProduct.Id` may `OemSegmentation.OemProductId` should  `dbo.OemSegmentation.OemProductId`

Comment: Post the `actual error` and `query`!!

Comment: Don't include the schema name when referencing columns in your queries! doing so is deprecated and your code will suddenly break in a future version of SQL Server. Instead use well chosen aliases. For example `MT` for `OemMediaType`, and perhaps `Prd` for `OemProduct ` and `Plt` for `OemPlatform`

Comment: the actual error is - Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spGetLegacyCmapForImport, Line 49 [Batch Start Line 7]
The multi-part identifier "dbo.OemSegmentation.OemProductId" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spGetLegacyCmapForImport, Line 50 [Batch Start Line 7]
The multi-part identifier "dbo.OemSegmentation.OemPlatformId" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spGetLegacyCmapForImport, Line 51 [Batch Start Line 7]
The multi-part identifier "dbo.OemSegmentation.OemMediaTypeId" could not be bound.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please point out where changes occurred. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular formatted initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have aliased your table, use the alias to use TWO PART names for columns. i.e `[TableAlias].[ColumnName]`

I belive you have use `column` namd **`Id`** in all your tables commonly, so whenever you are picking `Id` column just go for `[TableName].Id`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you missed join: "INNER JOIN dbo.OemSegmentation"

[image]

Comment: I shouldn't need that though should I?

Comment: Yes you should or change the subsequent join condition for example: you are using "OemSegmentation.OemProductID" in inner join condition but have not used the OemSegmentation table so it is throwing the exception mentioned by you.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.